# Is this code O(n) or O(logn)?

Tags: java, big-o

It's only checking the for loop 1/3n times, so it's still technically linear I guess? However I don't really understand why it wouldn't be O(logn), because many times a code with O(logn) running time ends up checking around 1/3n. Does O(logn) always divide the options by 2 every time?

```
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i+3)
    a = a+i;
```

Comment: When you double *n*, does the number of times your loop runs double? Or does it add a constant?

Comment: Your example is O(n); because it is linear. Consider something like [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for a logarithmic algorithm.

Comment: that makes sense hobbs. thanks for making it clear

Comment: Small nitpick, but the `;` after `i = i + 3` is a syntax error.

Comment: my bad, didnt mean to write that

Answer (score 2):

With time-complexity analysis, constant factors do not matter.  You could do 1,000,000 operations per loop, and it will still be O(n).  Because the constant 1/3 doesn't matter, it's still O(n).  If you have `n` at 1,000,000, then 1/3 of `n` would be much bigger than `log n`.

From the [Wikipedia entry on Big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant):

> Let k be a constant. Then:
>
> ```
> O(kg) = O(g) if k is nonzero.
> ```

Comment: rgettman, I have one question. What if inside the for loop, we had `n = n-2;` following `a = a+i;`? What would be Big-O in this case?

Comment: @user3251142 Still O(n).  The number of iterations would be about `n/5` instead of `n/3` (using the original value of `n`).  I'm assuming you would be adding curly braces so that `n=n-2` would be part of the loop.

Comment: Ask yourself if the number of iterations in the `for` loop will still be proportional to the original value of `n`.

Comment: well itll be (n-2*c)/3 or something.. right? which if you double n, the running time wont be doubled the same way... will it be?

Comment: @user3251142 All that `2*c` and `/3` stuff are operations with constants.  It's still O(n).  The way to make such a loop O(log n) is either to divide `n` by a constant every loop or to multiply `i` by a constant every loop.

Comment: what about if inside the for loop i had this: `if (n%3 == 2) n = 9;`. If n had remainder 2, the code would end really quickly! Doesn't this create huge variance?

Comment: isnt that both O(n) and O(9)?

Comment: I know the answer is probably O(n) but how can it be if it has the possibility of ending the loop so quickly?

Comment: @user3251142 It depends on what question is being asked.  If the question is what's the upper bound, then it's still O(n) because the loop could execute k*n times (for some constant k).  If it's the average time, your loop will be constant in 1/3 of cases and O(n) in the other 2/3, so the average time will be 2/3 of what it would be without the `if`, but that's still a constant multiplier so the average is still O(n).  Computing the variance or standard deviation is over my head, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

your code has complexity O(n), `O(n)/3 == a * O(n) == O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

It is order of n `O(n)` and not `O(logn)`. 
It because the run time increases linearly with the increase in `n`

For more information take a look at this graph and hopefully you will understand why it is not  logn
https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/fig/log_graph.gif

Answer (score 1):

The running Time is `O(n)` (in unit complexity measure).